# How to let R predict user input

Tags: r

Let's say I have this function that returns the coefficients of a linear model:

```
lmfun<-function(df,yname,xname){
  y<-deparse(substitute(yname))
  x<-deparse(substitute(xname))
  f<-as.formula(paste0(y,"~",x))
  lm.fit<-do.call("lm",list(data=quote(df),f))
  coef(lm.fit)
}
```

Now using this function on `mtcars` I can type:

```
lmfun(mtcars,yname=mpg,disp)
```

However, how do I get R to predict a user's input just like it happens in several packages? That is before I finish typing `mpg`, R has already made a suggestion.

Comment: How do you do it? You make a PR to RStudio or RTVS or whichever IDE/editor you're using, expanding their intellisense capabilities to handle your situation

Comment: Oh, I see! I thought there was some programming  trick involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want `match.arg`. For instance:

```
lmfun <- function(df, yname, xname){
  y <- match.arg(deparse(substitute(yname)), names(df))
  x <- match.arg(deparse(substitute(xname)), names(df))
  f <- as.formula(paste0(y, "~", x))
  lm.fit <- do.call("lm", list(data = quote(df), f))
  coef(lm.fit)
}
lmfun(mtcars, yname = mp, dis)
# (Intercept)        disp 
# 29.59985476 -0.04121512
```

Of course, it has to be possible to unambiguously match the names:

```
lmfun(mtcars, yname = mp, d)
# Error in match.arg(deparse(substitute(xname)), names(df)) : 
#   'arg' should be one of “mpg”, “cyl”, “disp”, “hp”, “drat”, “wt”, “qsec”,
# “vs”, “am”, “gear”, “carb”
```

This time it didn't work as `d` could be `disp` or `drat`.

Comment: @NelsonGon, does that help? Or are you looking just for this autocompletion that Hong Ooi mentioned in the comments?

Comment: Thanks. I am perhaps looking at autocompletion. However, could you clarify what this does?

Comment: @NelsonGon, in the example instead of writing `mpg` and `disp` it was enough to write `mp` and `dis` because `match.arg` successfully matched them using `names(df)`.

Comment: Oh, that helps too. I'll accept this answer as it seems to simplify typing too. However what if a user only provides `mg`? That is not the first two but the first and last.

Comment: @NelsonGon, that won't work and, say, the autocompletion in RStudio wouldn't suggest `mpg` for `mg` either. And that's reasonable since accepting `mg` is a much stronger requirement. If you want that, then using `grep` with a certain regex pattern (specified by what kind of pattern you are ready to accept) would work, but I think it's not a great practice.