# How to define a function so that the R studio can predict its variable?

Tags: r, rstudio

For example, we type `mat` then the R studio predicts as follows:

```
matrix(data, nrow = rows, ncol = cols)
```

How to define my function so that the R studio can predict its variables ?

If I define my funtion `foo(x,y)` as an additon `x+y` and  export by `#'@export` in my package then R studio can not predict its variable names `x,y` but only its function name `foo()`.

**What I wanted was something similar to that stated here:** [How to let R predict user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169628/how-to-let-r-predict-user-input)
That is before I finish typing the column name, R has started predicting my input.

---

Thank you for the answer of @piece  !! I can do it

Comment: I am not sure if one can do that yet. But it should be more of a feature request for RStudio.

Comment: Thank you for edition and reply @Ronak Shah.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to let R predict user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54169628/how-to-let-r-predict-user-input)

Comment: This is only quick reply for @NelsonGon, I will read and try .

Comment: Thank you for @RLave. and happy to hear that I can force.it...Now I try the NelsonGon method...but now I do not success.

Comment: I misspelled, I meant you CAN'T force this in a package, imo (sorry about that). I don't think that answer would help you achieve this, head over to https://community.rstudio.com/latest and ask there.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply @RLave,...I change the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a function `foo`:

```
foo <- function(x, y){
  x + y
}
```

In RStudio, go to `Tools > Global Options > Code > Edit Snippets` and add the following one:

```
snippet foo
    foo(x = ${1:x}, y = ${2:y})
```

Then if you type `foo` and hit `tab` you should have your snippet available.

[image]

Comment: Does this predict variable names? I mean not the function but the variable(column?)

Comment: I have tried, but the prediction is only `foo()` and not `foo(x,y)`. ...Or ..I am wrong ? So,... and the method of @pieca is only available  on my computer, I want to give the variable name prediction on users computer for my package.

Comment: @CamfordOxbridge If you hit enter on the snippet as in my answer then you will get `foo(x = x, y = y)` in the console. If that's not what you were looking for, then sorry, I probably misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thank you for reply @piece.  I have tried in many times (the definition of `foo()` is in the global environment) but the prediction is not changed after the edition of snippet. In my country, the night coming, so I will try tomorrow.

Comment: @pieca I think you misunderstood. The goal was to say if I want to write `foo(Species,Sepal.Length)`, then RStudio(R) automatically predicts Species once I start writing Sp, this answer is unnecessary because RStudio already does what you're stating even without adding a snippet. Just my two cents!

Comment: @NelsonGon ok, I see. I would phrase this as: How to automatically trigger [code autocompletion](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion) instead of waiting for the user to hit `Tab`. Currently it is triggered like that after you write first 3 letters. So if you define a variable named `Species` (or you have an argument with that name) then you need to write 'Spe'. If you want to move this 'threshold' to one or two letters then it's a deal with RStudio, as others said.

Comment: By make a space in front of  `foo(x = ${1:x}, y = ${2:y})` by `tab` key, the snippet code goes well !! I do not know why but if I make the space by `space` key, the snippet code does not work well. So, This edition of snippet is only my computer, I want to give this edition of snippet for users computer.